# TFS how to customize templates in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to customize the work items on TFS, I'm using microsoft scrum 2.0 template. How can I do it?

Comment: there must be some import utility in TFS which does that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download TFS 2010 Power Tools to get the process editor installed. Link: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Comment: Thanks @Morten, I'm downloading and trying, will see if it works

Comment: Almost :), I could open the template for editing, but then I've faced another problem related to the tool, and searching around, the recommendation is to modify it manually. However, the recommendation was good enough, so, thanks again.

Comment: I'm looking for a version compatible with team explorer 2012, does it exist?